# Is there anything like getOrDefault when putting a value into the java8 map?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

In java8, when getting some value from a map, we can write:

```
int keyCount=countMap.getOrDefault(key,0);
```

which is equal to:

```
if(countMap.contains(key)){
    keyCount=countMap.get(key);
}else{
    keyCount=0;
}
```

Problem is that is there any elegant way to replace below codes:

```
if(countMap.keySet().contains(key)){
    countMap.put(key,countMap.get(key)+1);
}else{
    countMap.put(key,1);
}
```

Comment: Look at 'computeIfAbsent', part of the Map interface

Comment: Another variant `countMap.put(key, countMap.containsKey(key) ? countMap.get(key) + 1 : 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As holger mentioned as well, you can simply use [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) as :

```
countMap.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)
```

Notice the documentation states its implementation as well:

The default implementation is equivalent to performing the following steps for this map, then returning the current value or null if absent:

```
V oldValue = map.get(key);
V newValue = (oldValue == null) ? value :
             remappingFunction.apply(oldValue, value);
if (newValue == null)
    map.remove(key);
else
    map.put(key, newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) method, also added in Java 8. That method takes in the key you are using, as well as a `BiFunction` to compute what the new value should be, based on the key and the existing value. So in your case, it would like something like the following:

```
countMap.compute(key, (k, oldValue) -> oldValue == null ? 1 : oldValue + 1);
```

When the key you give does not yet exist in the map, the oldValue in the `BiFunction` will be `null`; if you return `null` in the `BiFunction`, nothing gets put into the map.

It takes a little getting used to, but it's a very powerful method once you get the hang of it. It may be more readable (though much more verbose) with a method reference instead of the inline lambda:

```java
    countMap.compute(key, this::incrementOrSetToOne);

    // ... some other code ...

    private Integer incrementOrSetToOne(KeyType key, Integer oldValue) {
        return oldValue == null ? 1 : oldValue + 1;
    }
```

Comment: It’s even simpler to use `countMap.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)`

Comment: @Holger Yes it is. I always forget about `merge`. Thanks for noting it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are not familar with the `merge` method:

```
countMap.put(key, countMap.getOrDefault(key,0)+1);
```